# Selectize dropdown width independent of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I am trying to use Selectize to render a dropdown of very long labels.  The text can be pretty wide, but the input has a constraint on width.  Selectize perfectly wraps the text (in both the input and drop downs) but ideally the drop down would be able to scale wider than the input to allow better readability.  Is it possible to get Selectize to have a dropdown width independent of the input?

```
<select style="width:300px" multiple>
<option value="">Enter some tags...</option>
<option value="1" selected>QID7_4 : Where do you store your digital photos? Check all that apply.-On a cloud service like iCloud, Dropbox, Google Drive, or Amazon Cloud</option>
<option value="2">QID5_2 : What do you take pictures of most often? Please rank the following / by drag and drop.-Friends and social activities</option>
<option value="3">QID13_5 : How important is it to you that your photos are organized in the / following ways?-By quality (including favorites)</option>
```

Current look:

[image]

Desired look:
[image]

The idea is the text is much more readable if the dropdown expands to wrap less.

[Example jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DmLdh/12/)

Comment: I do not get your question 100%? can you explain

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Updated with images explaining current vs desired functionality

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The widths of each label are set dynamically through JS.
To overwrite that how about doing something like this:

```
.selectize-dropdown {
    width: 600px !important;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DmLdh/13/)

Comment: Too easy!  Thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: @rapidninja Great! Glad it helped.

Comment: Thanks! What about `min-width`, just in case?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel yes, `min-width` should work also.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan I just tried this and setting the `width` seems to have no effect... Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel I think you can make another answer, as some people might found your answer more suitable for them than mine.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan okay.  I just did that.

Answer (score 9):

When the dropdown should change it's width dynamically to the largest option:

```
.selectize-dropdown {
  width: auto !important;
}

.selectize-dropdown [data-selectable], .selectize-dropdown .optgroup-header {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Robin's Answer didn't work for me. However the following did.

```
.selectize-input {
    min-width: 600px !important;
}
```

Comment: But that's not independent of input

Comment: You're right @Oleg. OP's intention is to make the dropdown "text is much more readable if the dropdown expands to wrap less." from my understanding, not to make it strictly have some specific width.

Answer (score 0):

```
.selectize-control {
  width: 90% !important;
}
```

This would allow you to have it be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it adapt to the content and restrict maximum width by this:

```
.selectize-dropdown {
  width: max-content !important;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```